# How to watch array changed outside service?

Tags: angularjs

I have some directive and inject in it custom service.
I'm using this some variables from services in this directive and i would watch changes inside directive.

```
$CustomServices.someCollection = [];


    $scope.$watchCollection('$CustomServices.someCollection', function(newCol, oldCol, scope) {
...........................
    });
```

Is it possible to do something like this or only inside watch in Service?

Comment: why you do not provide that value as binding of the directive, so it will be refreshed when the value changes? You can even restructure your directive to be a component and use the `$onChanges(changesObj)` hook

Comment: @quirimmo i do something like that assign varibale from service to local $scope in directive $scope.collection = $customServices.collection and now i watch this variable that is in the same scope